# update table based on another table with condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables, having some difficulties in updating the table based on another table with condition

```
update table1 
    set val = (Select case 
                        when (ST_Intersects(t1.geom,t2.geom) and ST_Intersects(t1.geom,t3.geom)) then 100
                        when ST_Intersects(t1.geom,t3.geom) then 50 
                        when ST_Intersects(t1.geom,t2.geom) then 25 
                        else 0 
                      End 
              from table1 t1, 
                   table2 t2, 
                   table3 t3 
            where t1 = id and t2 = id and t3 = id)
```

ends with the following error

> "ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
>   SQL state: 21000"

How to solve this issue?

Comment: `How to solve this issue?` - By not using a sub-query that returns more than one value.  The error message is very specific and easy to understand.  If you want a different answer than that, you need to explain what you're trying to do so that we can help.

Comment: The condition `where t1 = id and t2 = id and t3 = id` makes no sense and is invalid syntax. `t1` is a table reference, you cannot compare that to a column.